# Tikzpicture match box width and column width

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, box

I can't find a way to match the box width of a tikzpicture and the column width.

Here is the code :

```
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=primary_shade3, fill=white, thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=white, text=primary_shade3]

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
        \item[$\bullet$] De plus en plus de patients et de moins en moins de personnel
        \item[$\bullet$] Perte d'information lors du suivi à partir d'observations visuelles
        \item[$\bullet$] Contraintes de coût, de portabilité et d'utilisabilité des nouvelles \\
                         plate-formes
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} 
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Problématique};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the result : 
[image]

As you can see, the right of the box is outside the columnwidth... Do you know how to fix this ?

Best

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete document (mwe: minimal working example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use minipages in a tikz node. The problem was that the inner and outer `sep`s were added which made the box overshoot. **EDIT**: I added a typeout that shows a bit what is done. (Of course one has to subtract these values twice, they are added left and right. And yes, `tcolorbox` as pointed out by Ignasi in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444305/121799) does all that for you, nevertheless I thought the question was why that happens. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{primary_shade3}{rgb}{0.66,0.0,0.66} 
\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=primary_shade3, fill=white, thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner ysep=10pt},
fancytitle/.style={fill=white, text=primary_shade3}}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}
-\pgflinewidth}
\typeout{the\space line\space width\space is\space\the\linewidth,\space and\space
the\space text\space width\space is\space\mywidth}
\node [mybox,text width=\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}
-\pgflinewidth] (box){%
\begin{itemize}
        \item[$\bullet$] De plus en plus de patients et de moins en moins de personnel
        \item[$\bullet$] Perte d'information lors du suivi à partir d'observations visuelles
        \item[$\bullet$] Contraintes de coût, de portabilité et d'utilisabilité des nouvelles \\
                         plate-formes
    \end{itemize}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Problématique};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine, thx but why do we have to add inner et outer sep of 2pt ?

Comment: @Maxouille You do not have to, this is just a simple trick to *know* what these dimensions are. You could also read out the predefined values with `\pgfkeysgetvalue`, do you want me to change the answer accordingly?

Comment: If you can it would be great :)

Comment: @Maxouille Done.

Answer (score 9):

An easier solution would be to use `tcolorbox`. It's default size is always adjusted to `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\definecolor{primary_shade3}{rgb}{0.66,0.0,0.66} 

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=primary_shade3,
    coltitle=primary_shade3,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
        colframe=white,
        colback=white,
        size=fbox
    },
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mybox}{Problématique}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\bullet$] De plus en plus de patients et de moins en moins de personnel
   \item[$\bullet$] Perte d'information lors du suivi à partir d'observations visuelles
   \item[$\bullet$] Contraintes de coût, de portabilité et d'utilisabilité des nouvelles plate-formes
    \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer (+1) ! i would add the package  `enumitem` and than for itemize use: `\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, leftmargin = *]
    \item   De plus en plus ... \end{itemize}`